# How do I check the version of Ubuntu I am running?

Tags: command-line, gui, system, versions

How can I check my current Ubuntu version through the command-line and GUI?

Comment: Since this came up in my search first I'll post one alternative: checking `/etc/apt/sources.list` and seeing what repo it's pulling from. This was the only way I could figure out what Ubuntu image I was running inside of a `docker run -it --rm` which apparently doesn't install `lsb_release`

Answer (score 713):

As said in the [official page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckingYourUbuntuVersion), use:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Your version appears on the "Description" line. If you just want that line, type `lsb_release -d`.

If you want to check it through your desktop environment, you can check ***System Settings → Details***, which shows the data like this:

[image: Display of "System Settings → Details"]

Alternatives are:

- `hostnamectl`
- `cat /etc/*ease`

---

See a sample output of `lsb_release`, `hostnamectl`, and `cat /etc/*ease` calls:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS          # <-- here
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
```

```
$ hostnamectl 
   Static hostname: XXX
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Machine ID: 3d6dcfdd7b9f41dbb62b0e8cd75014ae
           Boot ID: 4ff04a6baed54e719592f3255005a235
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS                # <-- here
            Kernel: Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

```
$ cat /etc/*ease
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"  # <--- here
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

Comment: why is it this weird command? I can't ever remember it. Why not something like `os -v`. Its sort of annoying.

Comment: Seems like the 80's had a lot of good things, including simple and easy to remember UNIX commands!

Comment: Ah, in good ol' plain DOS it was simply `ver`

Comment: @CharlieParker See [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base).

Comment: Ubuntu's official LTS Docker image (`ubuntu:xenial`) does _not_ have `lsb_release`; I had to parse `/etc/os_release` as noted in another answer.

Comment: @CharlieParker According to `man lsb_release`, LSB stands for [Linux Standard Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Standard_Base).

Comment: @CharlieParker Adding the following to your .bashrc: `export OS_CODE_NAME=$(lsb_release -cs); export OS_CODE_VERSION=$(lsb_release -rs)` allows you do a `env | grep OS`, which might be a bit more convenient.

Comment: @kap alias ver="lsb_release -ds"

Comment: @CharlieParker `alias os="lsb_release -a"`. I agree this should be easier by default, but the beauty of UNIX is it allows you to fix stuff like this yourself without much of a fuss.

Comment: This does not seem to be working in Ubuntu 18.  In 16 it does (and in the docs you linked, it shows 14).

Comment: `bash: lsb_release: command not found` and `E: Unable to locate package lsb_release` on Ubuntu 18

Comment: @JoãoRochadaSilva It's actually from the 2000's.

Comment: Code for ones which just needs short release description: `sb_release -d | grep -ioP ':\s+\K(.+?$)'`

Answer (score 243):

Use:

```
cat /etc/*release
```

In my case it produced the following output:

```
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.2
DISTRIB_CODENAME=rafaela
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="14.04.3 LTS, Trusty Tahr"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="14.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
```

Comment: `cat /etc/lsb-release`

Comment: On current mint releases `/etc/upstream-release/lsb-release`might be of interest as well.

Comment: This works everywhere I tested. lsb_release doesn't work on all versions. for example in Ubuntu 16.04 on Docker.

Comment: In my experience this is a more robust approach, some distributions will not have the lsb_release command

Comment: worked on my docker image

Comment: How to get just the DISTRIB_CODENAME e.g. "xenial" ?

Comment: using command to get directly `grep 'CODENAME' /etc/lsb-release | cut -d'=' -f2`

Comment: Good answer, as Ubuntu image installed from docker does not have lsb-release installed.

Comment: best solution, work in most of cases.

Comment: This one works also on WSL

Answer (score 65):

Use this in the terminal to show the details about the installed Ubuntu "version":

```
lsb_release -a
```

This may be more verbose than you need - maybe you just wanted to see `15.4`? It can be shown separately by the option `-r` (`--release`):

```
$ lsb_release -r
Release:        15.04
```

Add `-s` (`--short`) for use in a script:

```
$ lsb_release -r -s
15.04
```

See the further examples for the more useful options `-c` (`--codename`) and `-d` (`--description`), and both combined:

```
$ lsb_release -c
Codename:       vivid
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
$ lsb_release -dc
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Codename:       vivid
```

---

Note you can get similar information about the currently running kernel, and the hardware by the similar command:

```
$ uname -a
Linux mybox 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:04:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: `lsb_release -r -s` was what i was looking for, thanks

Comment: `lsb_release -rs` and `lsb_release -cs` are very useful in scripts.

Answer (score 15):

Executing this in Terminal will give you all of the information you could possibly need:

```
lsb_release -a
```

And you can access it in the GUI by going `System Settings > Details`:

[image]