# can't install i386 packages on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line

I am using the version Ubuntu 18.04.4 trying to add i386. I Have tried to install it via the command:

`echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

And I get the eror

`bash: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch: Permission denied`

I already tried to use the methods:

- `echo "foreign-architecture i386" > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`

and

- `sudo dpkg --foreign-architecture i386`

I simply get no output out of any of these. I have already tried to use the command:

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

It puts the output:

`dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'`

I have tried to check if it is already installed or not via the command:

`sudo dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

which I get the same bug with the previously mentioned command. I have tried to purge it with the command:

`sudo apt-get purge ".:i386"`

Which returned the eror code of:

```
E: Sub-process dpkg --set-selections returned an error code (2)
E: Couldn't record the approved state changes as dpkg selection states
```

These are the references of pages I have used but couldn't get any answers from:

- [How do I check the version of Ubuntu I am running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/686239/how-do-i-check-the-version-of-ubuntu-i-am-running)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462579/ubuntu-dpkg-add-architecture-i386-throwing-error-add-architecture-unknown
- http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/01/install-wine-5-0-stable-ubuntu-18-04-19-10/
- https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu
- [Trying to install wine32 i386 packages on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144799/trying-to-install-wine32-i386-packages-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiarch is enabled by default on 18.04

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` to the question. Do you problems installing Wine? Did you tried to use [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205596/66509).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the disturbing file

```
sudo rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Then you can add it with

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Comment: When ı used the command `sudo rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch  `I get the error `rm: cannot remove '/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch': No such file or directory`

Comment: My fault `sudo rm  /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures`

Comment: I still get the eror `rm: cannot remove '/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/architectures': No such file or directory` Is there a command to install multiarch again? I might have removed it in a accident.

Comment: last ditch from me grep -ri foreign /etc/dpkg/